# Pass OData query options to another OData API ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest, asp.net-web-api2, odata

I'm creating an ASP.NET OData v4 controller which in turn needs to be able to call another OData API. The models between the two APIs are identical so I would like a way for the query options passed to this API to flow through to the second OData API.

I can access the raw odata query values in the API and build up another query to pass to the second API, but it would be better if they could just be passed on.

Comment: did you solve your problem without parsing the parameters and passing them on to the other apis?