# ASP.NET Core OData creating generic pass through controller for underlying APIs

Tags: asp.net-core, odata

Scenario:

1. There are multiple APIs on async pattern. Each API has its own query option and its JSON request body
2. Each API only returns 202 and a custom response header
3. I want to have a single API, which will take all the possible query options and request JSON body and then call the underlying individual APIs (based on some parameter in request body)
4. I want this single API to be completely pass-through, so that whatever the client passes in query option and request body, it can be directly passed to the underlying API without any code changes in main API

This is similar to another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46686739/pass-odata-query-options-to-another-odata-api-asp-net) which doesn't have any answers. Does the latest version of OData support this scenario easily?

Comment: OData is a data access protocol that is primarily used to query and update data, and is not designed to function as an API middleware or proxy.